# How can I configure XStream to deserialize an empty implict collection as an empty list using annotations?

Tags: java, xml, xstream

How can I configure XStream to deserialize an empty implict collection as an **empty list** using annotations?  Currently I'm getting a `null` list, and XStream is nulling out the empty list that I'm preinitializing the field with.

---

**Background:**

I am using XStream to deserialize some XML from another application that contains an implicit list of elements.  For instance:

```
<implicitCollectionContainer>
    <implicitCollectionElement field="sdf"/>
    <implicitCollectionElement field="ioj"/>
</implicitCollectionContainer>
```

XStream correctly parses the above XML into a collection with two elements.

When that system has no results, it returns an empty tag:

```
<implicitCollectionContainer/>
```

XStream parses the above XML, but it gives me a `null` collection.  I would prefer an empty collection of size 0, which is easier to deal with.

XStream is actually fighting against me, since I preinitialize the field on the POJO with an empty collection, which XStream then clears.

---

**Example Code:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    XStream xstream = new XStream();
    xstream.setMode(XStream.NO_REFERENCES);
    xstream.ignoreUnknownElements();

    Class[] xStreamClasses = {ImplicitCollectionContainer.class, ImplicitCollectionElement.class};
    xstream.processAnnotations(xStreamClasses);

    // setup security for xstream
    // see: http://x-stream.github.io/security.html
    xstream.addPermission(NoTypePermission.NONE);
    xstream.addPermission(NullPermission.NULL);
    xstream.addPermission(PrimitiveTypePermission.PRIMITIVES);
    xstream.allowTypeHierarchy(Collection.class);
    xstream.allowTypes(xStreamClasses);

    String xml1 = "<implicitCollectionContainer/>";
    ImplicitCollectionContainer obj1 = (ImplicitCollectionContainer) xstream.fromXML(xml1);
    System.out.println("obj1 implicit collection: " + obj1.implicitCollection);

    String xml2 =  "<implicitCollectionContainer><implicitCollectionElement field=\"sdfd\"/><implicitCollectionElement field=\"ioj\"/></implicitCollectionContainer>";
    ImplicitCollectionContainer obj2 = (ImplicitCollectionContainer) xstream.fromXML(xml2);
    System.out.println("obj2 implicit collection: " + obj2.implicitCollection + " size=" + obj2.implicitCollection.size());

}

@XStreamAlias("implicitCollectionContainer")
public static class ImplicitCollectionContainer {
    @XStreamImplicit
    ArrayList<ImplicitCollectionElement> implicitCollection = new ArrayList<>(0);
}

@XStreamAlias("implicitCollectionElement")
public static class ImplicitCollectionElement {
    @XStreamAsAttribute
    String field = "x";

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ImplicitCollectionElement[field=" + field + "]";
    }
}
```

**Example Code Output:**

```
obj1 implicit collection: null
obj2 implicit collection: [ImplicitCollectionElement[field=sdfd], ImplicitCollectionElement[field=ioj]] size=2
```

---

**Versions:**

I am using XStream 1.4.11.1 on Java 8.

---

**Lawyering:**

This is not a dup of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19534475/parsing-with-xstream-empty-tags-and-collections), because I'm asking for an annotation-based configuration solution, while that one explicitly asks for a solution that *avoids* annotations.  I know I can configure a converter using annotations, but I'm hoping for a more elegant solution.